# How to adjust video source depending on viewers screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, video, size, screen, resolution

Ok ,sorry for I m noob. I ll try to be specific.

This is what I red on w3Schools:

"Note: Do not rescale video with the height and width attributes! Downsizing a large video with the height and width attributes forces a user to download the original video (even if it looks small on the page). The correct way to rescale a video is with a program, before using it on a page."

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_height.asp

So, I cant just scale video like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
#video{
  width:426; height:240;
};
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
#video{
  width:1280; height:720;
};
}
```

```html
<video id='video' controls>
    <source src="Showreel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I need to set different video sizes (qualities) that will be shown depending on the viewers screen resolution. Can someone point me in some direction? Maybe there is some thread that you know of; JQuery/pure JS/css/any solutions...

Comment: Please add the tag of the programming language that you would like to use.

Comment: Take a look at Adaptive Bit Rate streaming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming). It will often actually work, on the browser side, with no need for anything beyond the video tag, with the caveat that different browsers support different ABR streaming formats. Take a look at this for the Apple HLS format for example: http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/hls/. Take a look also at this for some background on how HTML5 can be extended to support any streaming protocol: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/ (look at 'Media Source Extensions (MSE)').